# Deployment azure cloud services with application downloaded from blob

Tags: eclipse, azure, deployment, blob

i deploy my cloud services package from eclipse to azure. First it will upload my application to the blob storage. ( This is standard i can't change this )  And then it will starting sending the azure package and the update is started. Everything works fine.

But what will happen when i remove the application from the blob after the update is succeeded? Because after a few day the azure servers will be recycled and new servers will be available with the same azure package. Will the new server still get the application ? Is the application somewhere available in azure for redeploy azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what will happen when i remove the application from the blob after
>   the update is succeeded? Because after a few day the azure servers
>   will be recycled and new servers will be available with the same azure
>   package. Will the new server still get the application ? Is the
>   application somewhere available in azure for redeploy azure?

Azure Service Fabric (service responsible for managing your application) reads the application package file from blob storage and copies it to another location within its infrastructure. So even if you delete the files from blob storage, Azure has a copy of your application and will deploy the application using that copy.

In short, Azure is not dependent on the files in your blob storage after it has created the deployment.

Comment: Thanks, i though it will work this way but i couldn't find my answer anywere.